# Using ::after with an image tag?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to append text to images using the `::after` pseudo-selector?

```
img[src="images/interface-zoom-buttons.png"]::after {
    content: "these are the zoom buttons";
}
```

The desire is to use the selector to provide a caption (other styling will be applied to the content of the selector) for images that get used over and over again in multiple HTML documents.

In the above example the image appears correctly and you can see that the appropriate CSS has been applied, but the content (supplied by the selector) is not seen in the output.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the dupe @JukkaKKorpela. I had searched for one, but had limited my search to the image tag and did not see this one come up in the suggested list of dupes.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

An img tag can not have child elements. Because `img` is a [void element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#void-element) and its content model never allows it to have contents under any circumstances.

`::after` creates a pseudo element as the last child of its parent.

So `img::after` will not work ultimately because the browser will not allow it based on definition.

What you can do is to contain the `img` in a container and have `::after` on the container.

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/x2za91jw/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://www.gazette-ariegeoise.fr/IMG/jpg/test.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}
.container::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    content:"these are the zoom buttons";
}
```

Comment: HTML content models do not restrict what you can do in CSS. Browsers do.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Arbel. I was aware that I could after on the container I just couldn't find anything about images. I was hoping not to have to do some JavaScript trickery but I'm guessing that will be my only solution in this case.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Thanks I rephrased the sentence to be more clear.

Comment: @JayBlanchard You are welcome! Glad to be of help to you.