# The ::before element in css is working at all

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I am trying to change the opacity of a background image image without affecting the other elements by using `::before`. but it seems to not work even on different browsers.
here's the code:

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styling/style.css">
    <title>Gardening | Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- header -->
    <header>
        <nav>
            <h3 class="center">Gardenizo</h3>
<!-- search icon -->
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="a">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="a">Shop</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="a">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="a">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="a">See more</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

<!-- first section -->
    <section class="land_page">
        <div class="text center">
            <p>Bring freshness into your place.</p>
            <h1>Plants are awesome!</h1>
        </div>

<!-- background image -->
        <img src="./assets/plantsbg3.jpeg" class="img" alt="">
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the css:

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* variables */
:root{
    --header-color: white;
}



/* shared css */
.center{
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}
.a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}


/* header */
header{
    position: relative;
    background-color: var(--header-color);
    min-height: 80px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 12px black;
}
header nav{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 20px;
}
    header nav ul{
    display: flex;
    gap: .7cm;
    justify-content: center;
    list-style: none;
}


/* section 1 */
.land_page{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 500px;
    padding-top: 1cm;
}
.land_page .text{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 3cm;
}
.land_page .text h1{
    font-size: 4rem;
}
.land_page .img{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    margin-top: -7cm; 
}

.land_page .img::before{
    content: '';
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    opacity: 10%;
}
```

I tried the `$::before{ }` but still didn't work.

Comment: As a note, I assumed that you left out the comments' starting markers because of the fact you were using blockquotes to show the code, and they were interfering with the rendering somehow of the code in the question.  If this is not the case, please remove them.  Otherwise, I have fixed your formatting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS :after not adding content to certain elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949148/css-after-not-adding-content-to-certain-elements) - TL;DR. `pseudo` elements cannot be used on `img` tags. And, why not just the `opacity` on the `img` tag itself? Based on your markup, there is no reason to use a pseudo element.

Comment: [Read the doc !](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) **can not apply to replaced elements, such as `<img>`**

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is trying to set a `::before` pseudoelement on an `<img>` element. However, [replaced elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element), such as `<img>` and `<input>` elements, [cannot have pseudoelements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after#:%7E:text=Note%3A%20The%20pseudo%2Delements%20generated%20by%20%3A%3Abefore%20and%20%3A%3Aafter%20are%20contained%20by%20the%20element%27s%20formatting%20box%2C%20and%20thus%20don%27t%20apply%20to%20replaced%20elements%20such%20as%20%3Cimg%3E%2C%20or%20to%20%3Cbr%3E%20elements.).

> **Note:** The pseudo-elements generated by ::before and ::after are [contained by the element's formatting box](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content), and thus don't apply to [*replaced elements*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element) such as [`<img>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img), or to [`<br>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) elements.

You may want to wrap your `<img>` element in a non-replaced element, such as a `<div>`, and use that element's `::before` pseudoelement instead.

Comment: I'm down voting this since there are several duplicates - and the one that I closed with already has 172 upvotes.

Comment: You do you, but as someone who often finds StackOverflow results on Google I know it's easier to find the answer immediately instead of following a series of links to duplicate answers 

Comment: From Google are [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396469/why-dont-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-work-with-img-elements), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843035/does-before-not-work-on-img-elements), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70083216/pseudo-class-after-doesnt-work-on-img-element), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26371129/using-after-with-an-image-tag)... you might see the point. This answer only creates more noise on Stack Overflow - when there are several other duplicates. If your answer added something new, then maybe.